# Converting LMM to GLMM

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, glmm

I've fit my model using `lme` (in `nlme`, R). However, this is not normally distributed. Taking the log of the outcome variable makes it normal. But my professor wants me to use a `glmm` with a log link instead of transforming the variable. What would be a good R package to do this (and still include the autocorrelation I know exists in the longitudinal data - so not `glmer`).

```
tsmodel8 <- lme(totalsupport ~ time+I(time^2) + (various fixed effects), 
                random = ~1+time+I(time^2)|id, correlation=corCAR1(form = ~1 | id),
                weights = varExp(form = ~time), data = dat, na.action = "na.exclude",
                method = "ML")
```

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-51.4/topics/glmmPQL

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly.